# Journey Builder Salesforce data entry with upsert setting in the DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

We have a journey using **Salesforce data entry source** with the contact entry setting is **Re-entry anytime** and Entry criteria is **is updated**, we are using **Case** object.

We want to leverage this journey DE to update customer response into the same DE because we are sending a submit form to them in the journey.

So I have added a flag field called "Responded" in the journey DE and put a script in the submit form to update their response to this field in the journey DE.

The problem is that the journey DE only inserts new records into the DE and does not update existing ones. Therefore the script only works with Entry criteria is **is created** while we need to make it work with **is updated** criteria.

I tried to clear DE records then make the primary field on the Case ID field but it does not work and the journey stopped injecting the contacts with the same Case IDs.

How do I make the DE **upsert** Salesforce records in the journey?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, we think about using a separated DE for the customer response and updated information from the object record. We just wonder if we can do the upsert action in the journey DE

Comment: What is the script you're using to upsert to the Journey Data Extension?

Comment: @Macca this is my current script `UpdateData("My journey DE",1,"Case:Id", @case, "Responded", "True")` This will work with Journey Entry criteria is "is created" because the case ID here is unique but we want to make it work with "is updated" criteria

Comment: Without knowing data types and primary key, why not use UpsertDE? UpsertDE("My journey DE",1,"Case:Id", @case, "Responded", "True")

Comment: @Macca the thing is that "is updated" criteria will be used in the journey and our client will manually extract the data in the journey DE later, if I don't have consistent data in the journey DE, most likely they will see duplicate Case records with outdated information